# Scrapy spider unkown output

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Am new to Scrapy (webscraping in general), for a school project i am trying to collect job titles from a certain website .I am using the scrapy shell this is my request :

```
In [19]: job = response.xpath("//article/div/a/text()")

In [20]: job.getall()
```

this is the result that i got :

```
['\r\n                ',
 '\r\n            ',
 '\r\n                ',
 '\r\n            ']
```

as for the  HTML:

```
<article id="644613" class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs  ">

        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
        <div class="media-heading listing-item__title">
            <a href="https://www.tanitjobs.com/job/644613/ingénieur-net/?backPage=&amp;searchID=1585105963.7756" class="link">
            Ingénieur .NET

            </a>
        </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jobs = response.css("article.listing-item div.listing-item__title a::text").getall()
```

You can read more about selectors here:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html